# Python virtual environment lists no installed packages

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I created a virtual environment `mdpenv` by typing

```
$ conda create --name mdpenv
```

I activate it as

```
$ source /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/activate mdpenv
```

I try to list all packages installed in this environment, which I expect to be the same as the base environment, but I get nothing:

```
(mdpenv) $ conda list
# packages in environment at ~/.conda/envs/mdpenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

However, I clearly have many packages installed, for example:

```
(mdpenv) $ python
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import pandas
```

Why don't I get the list of the packages that my new virtual environment `mdpenv` is exposed to?

Answer (score 3):

Conda environments usually comes with default packages. If you want a clean environment, do:

```
conda create --no-default-packages -n myenv python=3.6
```

This will create a clean environment with no default packages. Environments are not a clone of your base. If you want everything in base on your environment, then you should clone base.

```
conda create --name base --clone myenv
```

You can change the behavior of default packages installed when creating a new environment by editing the .condarc file The .condarc is created automatically on your home directory the first time you run:

```
conda config
```

Configuration follows YAML syntax. With your editor of choice, navigate to:

```
create_default_packages:
  - pip
  - ipython
  - numpy 
  ...
```

You can remove or add packages you wish to be included in a default environment creation.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `python` into the shell (in the terminal), it looks for that file in the directories that are stored in the environment variable called `PATH`. You can see the value of this variable by typing `echo $PATH`.

When a conda environment is activated (including the base environment), the directory that stores the executables installed in the environment is added to the `PATH` variable. So when your base environment is activated, you'll see something like

```
/path/to/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

However, when you activate an environment, conda leaves the base environment on the `PATH`, and just adds the new environment to the front, like

```
/path/to/anaconda/envs/mdpenv/bin:/path/to/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Now, when you create an empty environment, conda installs no packages at all (hence the empty `conda list` output). However, the `python` from the base environment is still present on your `PATH`, so when you type `python`, the shell will find the Python installed in the base environment, and that Python loads all the packages installed in the base environment.

It is easy to test this behavior by checking the executable that Python is using and Python's path for importing packages:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/path/to/anaconda/bin/python
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/path/to/anaconda/lib/python37.zip', ...]
```

If you install `python` into your new environment, you'll find that you can't import any packages (since there isn't anything other than Python installed in that environment)